# DynamicFrame.fromDF causes extreme delay in writing to db using glueContext.write_from_options()

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a glue job, wherein I need to read data from 2 tables from SQL Server, perform some joins/transformation and write back to another new/truncated table in SQL Server. The size of the data to be written is 15GB approx.

I have tried 2 approaches as follows and see massive difference in performance.  I am looking at getting the job to completed in under 10 minutes.

**APPROACH 1 - Takes about 17 minutes to overall (Read data from SQL Server, transformations, writing to S3, Read from S3, writing back to SQL Server)**

- Read from SQLServer into spark dataframes  (3 - 5 seconds approx.)
- Perform transformation on spark dataframes  (5 seconds approx.)
- Write the data to a temporary storage to S3 (8 minutes approx.)
- Read from S3 using glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options()
  into a Dynamic Dataframe
- Write to SQLServer table using glueContext.write_from_options() (9 minutes)

**APPROACH 2 - Takes about 50 minutes to overall (Read data from SQL Server, transformations, writing back to SQL Server)**

- Read from SQLServer into spark dataframes (3 - 5 seconds approx.)
- Perform transformation on spark dataframes (5 seconds approx.)
- Convert spark dataframe a Dynamic Dataframe using
  DynamicFrame.fromDF()
- Write to SqlServer table using glueContext.write_from_options() (43 minutes)

I observed that in the second approach its taking more time even though I have avoided writing to S3 and read back from S3, by converting spark dataframe to Dynamic dataframe, and use it for writing to SQL Server.  Also the tables are truncated before writing the data to it.  I was expecting that by removing S3 R/write, i can get the job completed in 10 - 12minutes.

Am I missing something here? Any suggestions please.

**Code template for approach1:**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import time
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])


sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()


# STEP 1 -- READ DATA FROM TABLES INTO DATAFRAMES
# -----------------------------------------------
# STEP 2 -- PERFORM TRANSFORMATIONS IF ANY, AND WRITE TO DATALAKE - S3
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
df.write.mode("overwrite").csv("s3://<<bucket-name>>/temp_result")

# STEP 3 -- READ DATA FROM S3 INTO NEW DATAFRAMES
#------------------------------------------------
newdf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type='s3',connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://<<bucket-name>>/temp_result"]},format='csv')

# STEP 4 -- TRUNCATE TARGET TABLE AS ITS A FULL REFRESH ALWAYS IN THE TARGET TABLE
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cstmt = conn.prepareCall("TRUNCATE TABLE mytable_in_db");
results = cstmt.execute();

# STEP 5 -- WRITE TO TARGET TABLE FROM DATAFRAME
# ----------------------------------------------
glueContext.write_from_options(frame_or_dfc=newdf, connection_type="sqlserver", connection_options=connection_sqlserver_options)
job.commit()
```

**Code template for approach2:**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import time
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])


sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()


# STEP 1 -- READ DATA FROM TABLES INTO DATAFRAMES
# -----------------------------------------------
# STEP 2 -- PERFORM TRANSFORMATIONS IF ANY AND STORE TO df
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
  df contains transformed data
  
# STEP 3 -- CONVERT SPARK DATAFRAME TO DYNAMIC DATAFRAME
#--------------------------------------------------------
newdf2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext , "newdf2")

# STEP 4 -- TRUNCATE TARGET TABLE AS ITS A FULL REFRESH ALWAYS IN THE TARGET TABLE
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cstmt = conn.prepareCall("TRUNCATE TABLE mytable_in_db");
results = cstmt.execute();

# STEP 5 -- WRITE TO TARGET TABLE FROM DATAFRAME
# ----------------------------------------------
glueContext.write_from_options(frame_or_dfc=newdf2, connection_type="sqlserver", connection_options=connection_sqlserver_options)
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing same problem. From my `SQL Profiler` and `Activity Monitor` it seems that `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options()` is the weak spot.

I came to this conclusion after noticing lack of open sessions on the target instance (RDS SQL Server) when Glue is obtaining `dynamicFrame` from the source (also RDS SQL Server).

Important thing to notice - the idle state happens when bigger tables are to be retained from source (1-2+ million records).

I would suggest to try bypass `Glue`'s methods and go with `spark.read` method. Create your `dataFrame`, do all transforms and convert to `dynamicFrame` for load.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

```
tbl = df = self.spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://").option("user","").option("password","").option("dbtable","").option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").load()
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, and this is exactly what I did in my Approach2, wherein I used only write_from_options() to write to sql server.  This is approximately took about 50 mins. I am now trying with new feature of bulk loading from S3 to Sql server using the RDS Store procedures, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User.SQLServer.Options.S3-integration.html.  Will update on the status.